# How do I encode a file (such as PDF) to base64 in NetSuite

Tags: docusignapi, netsuite, encode

I need to send a PDF file from NetSuite to DocuSign via a POST call.  DocuSign requires it be base64 encoded.  The Encode module only converts strings and I've not found any other candidates to encode it.

Suggestions please.

Comment: are you responding to a POST or handling one? SS1 or SS2?

Comment: Oh.  Thank you.  I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: I removed the tag `pdf` because your question (and its answer, if there is one) is not *limited to* nor *specifically good for* nor *somewhat related to* the PDF file format. Any answer will work with any kind of file.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer.  The file object has a method .getContents().  This returns the contents of the file in base64 encoding.

So for a given/loaded file myFile, you just need myFile.getContents().